# Convert string representation of a list in sqlite3 database while making SELECT command

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an sqlite3 database, where one of the columns contains a string representation of a list (ex: "['hello', 'there', 'example']"). I need to use a SELECT command and the LIKE clause to extract rows where an element of such a 'list' contains a certain substring. I know how to build a command that extracts rows that have a column whose value contains a substring, but I do not know how to check if the individual elements of the 'list' in a column (that is represented as a string) contain a substring. Here's the code I know how to write for retrieving columns that contain a substring.

```
SELECT * FROM yourDatabase WHERE UPPER(column) LIKE UPPER(?)",('%'+substring+'%',)
```

Note: I could just read every row of the database convert that 'list' column into an actual list, and then check for the substring in the elements of that list, but that seems REALLY inefficient.

Comment: Are you checking for an entire word in the list, or a substring which might occur inside any word in that list?  They are the not the same things.

Comment: Also, please show some sample data for the column in question.

Comment: I am searched for a substring which might occur in a word in the list.

Comment: What you are trying to do here is bad design, won't scale, and shouldn't ever be recommended.  If you want to search a text for keywords, then use full text search, it was designed for this.

Comment: Would full-text search be more efficient than a one-many relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to do this. This will become less and less performant as your database increases in size. This is because when this query is performed, your DB engine has to scan linearly through every single row to perform some expensive string operations on that column.

What you want instead is a [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) or [one-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)). In the context of a real example, a StackOverflow post has many tags. With a many-to-many relationship, you'd have a table structure as follows:

```
posts 
id | integer

posts_have_tags
post_id | foreign key(posts)
tag_id  | foreign key(tags)

tags
id   | integer
name | string
```

You can efficiently ask questions like:

- Give me all the tags for post with ID = `x` (`SELECT * FROM tags LEFT JOIN posts_have_tags ON tags.id = posts_have_tags.tag_id WHERE posts_have_tags.post_id = x`)
- Give me all the posts tagged with a certain tag with id `x` (`SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN posts_have_tags ON posts.id = posts_have_tags.post_id WHERE posts_have_tags.tag_id = x`)
- Does a post with ID = x have a certain tag?

This scales better because the DB engine can build up efficiently queryable representations of these relationships.

Your other option is to use a NoSQL database which inherently will allow document store (typically JSON) that can do these things (although scanning is still inefficient usually).

As a side note, if you're using Postgres, recent versions have support for JSON columns [which can be efficiently queried](https://blog.codeship.com/unleash-the-power-of-storing-json-in-postgres/).